# A question about cpu utilization

Tags: cpu

Here's a question in the OS textbook about calculating the cpu utilization.
[image]
[image]

I've tried to write down the (A) by myself as below.

```
(35+303)/((3+0.05)5 + (30+0.05)3) = 99.6xx%
```

But I'm not sure if it is right.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).  Please give proper attribution to your sources.  We require you to provide a reference for the OS textbook you are copying from.

Comment: Please don't just show a formula/equation.  Tell us your reasoning and your approach and where you got that from.